Understanding expectation in a single-period market model
I'm auditing a course on stochastic finance. In there a problem was presented, the solution to which wuld be presented on the tutorial I have no access to as an auditor.
The problem goes a as follows:
Assume we have a single-period, single-asset model with a probability space $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t=0}^1, \mathbb{P}\right)$ and the interest rate $r$ equal to $0.$
Take  $S_0^1=1$ and $S_1^1 \in\left\{\frac34 S_0^1, \frac54S_0^1\right\}$. We are given a condition $(*)$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\max \left\{H_1 \cdot \left(S_1^1-1\right), 0\right\} = V_0 +H_1 \cdot [S_1^1- S_0^1]\right)=1$$
The task is to find find to find an equivalent probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ with $E_{\mathbb{Q}}[S_1^1] = S^1_0$ and use it to show that $E_{\mathbb{Q}}[\max\{S_1^1-1, 0\}]=V_0.$
I was able to set up equations from the condition $(*)$ and solve them to find the values $V_0$ and $H_1$ that satisfy it ($\frac18$ and $\frac12$ respectively). I also know that by the definition of equivalent prob. measure we must have $\mathbb{P} (A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(A) = 0.$
But I don't know how to proceed from there, eg. how to calculate expectation given that I don't now the probabilities with which $S_1^1$ takes either of the values. Is it just $H_1=\frac12$ I found? I'm confused as to what exactly the meaning of it is.

Do you know the significance of the condition (*) that is given to you? Also, you have a somewhat stylized setup where you can actually show under some conditions that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not depend on $\mathbb{P}$ iirc. I guess you may assume that the outcomes $\frac{3}{4}S_{0}^{1}, \frac{5}{4}S_{0}^{1}$ both happen with non-zero probability.

no, I don't think I know the significance of $(*).$
Tbh assuming the outcomes happen with non-zero prob. doesn't seem like helping me much (i.e. I don't see how that could be used to find that equiv. prob. measure $\mathbb{Q}$ or showing that $E_{\mathbb{Q}}[\max{S_1^1-1, 0}]=V_0.$

Since you assume interest rates to be zero you have to solve for the probability $q=\mathbb Q{S^1_1=\frac34S^1_0}$ that gives you $\mathbb E[S_1^1]=S_0^1,.$ (The probability $\mathbb Q{S^1_1=\frac54S^1_0}$ is automatically $1-q,.$) This is simple and gives you the full measure $\mathbb Q,.$ Can you proceed?
